# Obtaining body background color via Javascript (jQuery) in Webkit & Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, xhtml

This code only seems to work in Firefox. Safari and Opera don't like it:

```
alert($("<body>").css("background-color"));
```

I've tried other methods too which are even less successful.

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].styles.backgroundColor);
alert(document.body.styles.backgroundColor);
```

I've tested these browsers on Mac - and haven't tested this in IE (yet). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
alert($("body").css("background-color"));
```

(i.e. without the angle brackets around `body`). See the [jQuery docs on the CSS function](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#name), and the docs on [jQuery Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: Yep, you don't need the whole tag as the selector, just the tag name.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for this guys, I knew the whole tag was for creation of elements - just slipped past me on this occasion!